# Periodically post to LinkedIn company page through PHP API

Tags: php, api, cron, linkedin-api

I am building a simple service in PHP. It should do the following:

1. Check resource X if there are any updates through a CRON job.
2. If so, post the update(s) to a certain LinkedIn company page.

I have everything ready to go, apart from the LinkedIn bit.

Question: How do I authenticate to the LinkedIn API, so that the script can post to a company page, without requiring any user interaction such as logging in (as the script is triggered by a CRON job, not a person).

Comment: This could be of help : http://www.codexworld.com/login-with-linkedin-using-php/

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I have same problem.